# How to iterate through a list to find a match in thymeleaf?

Tags: thymeleaf

How can I rewrite the script below with out specifying the index[x]? and allow thymeleaf to iterate the whole list to see if it find a match of test.host == server.host.

```
<tr th:if="${server.host == test[1].host}">
    <td th:text ="${test[1].Status}"></td>
     <td th:text="${test[1].host}"></td>
    <td th:text="${test[1].version}"></td>
</tr>
```

It's not working the way I wanted it to work. It worked when I used index[x] to specify a host. I wanted it to iterate through the whole list. If test.host matches server.host. I don't want to specify an index[x]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can iterate using `th:each` on your collection/ array

```
<th:block th:each="item: ${test}">///item is a var name, test is your array
    <tr th:if="${server.host == item.host}">
       <td th:text="${item.Status}"></td>
       <td th:text="${item.host}"></td>
       <td th:text="${item.version}"></td>
    </tr>
 </th:block>
```